# I need to retrieve the last "order" and pass it to a mail

Tags: laravel

I need to retrieve the last "order" created on the mySql database and pass it to a mail in order to be able to print a receipt, but it does not matter what i try, in the mail view it's always undefined. any tips for a newbie?

this is the controller that and sends the mail

```
public function token(Request $request)
{

    $gateway = new \Braintree\Gateway([
        'environment' => 'sandbox',
        'merchantId' => 'jgvy755pfvwdcjzx',
        'publicKey' => 'qqpm93srfgwtx6dp',
        'privateKey' => 'd13ce21a7642606db73b12bb1300d3fd'
    ]);

    $clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

    if ($request->input('nonce') != null) {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'email' => 'email:rfc',
        ]);

        //# Storo l'ordine
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $address = $request->input('address');
        $phone = $request->input('phone');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $arr_id = $request->input('arr_id');
        $arr_quant = $request->input('arr_quant');
        $delivery_fee = $request->input('delivery_fee');
        //# Recupero tutti i piatti dell'ordine per calcolarne il totale
        $dishes = Dish::findMany($arr_id);
        $arrayLength = count($arr_id);
        $amount = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
            $amount +=  $dishes[$i]->price * $arr_quant[$i];
        }
        $amount += $delivery_fee;

        //#


        $newOrder = new Order();
        $newOrder->status = 1;
        $newOrder->address = $address;
        $newOrder->user_name = $name;
        $newOrder->user_surname = $last_name;
        $newOrder->phone = $phone;
        $newOrder->email = $email;
        $newOrder->total = $amount;
        $newOrder->save();
        // // storo l'array di IDs


        // Ciclo una volta per ogni piatto contenuto nell'ordine, salvo la relazione e la sua quantità
        for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
            $dish_id = $arr_id[$i];
            // Scrive nella tabella pivot dopo aver creato la relazione
            $newOrder->dishes()->attach([$dish_id => ['quantity' => $arr_quant[$i]]]);
            //
        }

        //#


        var_dump($request->input('nonce'));
        $nonceFromTheClient = $request->input('nonce');
        $gateway->transaction()->sale([
            'amount' => $amount,
            'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => True
            ]
        ]);


        Mail::to($email)->send(new PaymentConfirmationMail());
        return view('orders.success');
    }


    return view('orders.braintree', ['token' => $clientToken]);
}

public function success(Request $request)
{
    return view('orders.success');
}
```

}

this is the mail

```
class PaymentConfirmationMail extends Mailable
```

{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

```
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mails.payment_confirmation_mail');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your Mail class isn't being told anything about the new order - you need to pass it to it :

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new PaymentConfirmationMail($newOrder));
```

then in your Mail class you need to be prepared to receive it :

```
protected $newOrder;

public function __construct(Order $newOrder) {
    $this->newOrder = $newOrder
}
```

And also then pass the newOrder to the view :

```
public function build() {
    $newOrder = $this->newOrder;
    return $this->view('mails.payment_confirmation_mail')->with(compact('newOrder);
}
```

It should then be usable in your view with {{ $newOrder->something }}.

Comment: tried but Braintree crashes ( 500 internal server error) and i can't understand why. thank you very much anyway for trying to help me!

Comment: That should be unrelated. Once you've got the information from Braintree, there doesn't look to be any other involvement with it - so if you can fix the Braintree aspect of it, the approach above should then let you render the order in the view.